# Groovy lists and maps

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

i am writing my helper methods for selenium tests. One of them is :

```
    private static List<DataRow> parseTable(WebElement table) {
    List<WebElement> tableHeaders = table.findElements(By.tagName("th"))
    List<DataRow> dataRow = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tbody/tr")).collect {
        Map<String, String> columns = [:]
        it.findElements(By.tagName("td")).eachWithIndex { item, i ->
            columns[tableHeaders.get(i).text] = item.text
        }
        new DataRow(it, columns)
    }
    return dataRow
}
```

And i dont like this part:

```
 it.findElements(By.tagName("td")).eachWithIndex { item, i ->
        columns[tableHeaders.get(i).text] = item.text
    }
```

Is there a better way to make map from two lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def columns = [tableHeaders,it.findElements(By.tagName("td"))].transpose().collectEntries()
```

By way of an explanation:

Given:

```
def a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
def b = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Then

```
def c = [ a, b ].transpose()
assert c == [ [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ] ]
```

And:

```
def d = c.collectEntries()
assert d instanceof Map
assert d == [ a:1, b:2, c:3 ]
```

Comment: provided cardinality of `a` and `b` is same?

Comment: @dmahapatro Yeah, otherwise you get a number of elements in the map the same as the smaller of the two lists.  I assumed this was the case as the example above would behave the same (or crash if `tableHeaders` was shorter)

Comment: It makes sense when thinking from the perspective of `rows` and `columns`. If there is no element in the row for a column then that does not get transposed.
Conversely, if there is no column for a row then the element is neglected. For example:

`assert [['a', 'b'],[1, 2, 3]].transpose() == [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`
`assert [['a', 'b', 'c'],[1, 2]].transpose() == [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`

Comment: It can use more than 2 dimensions too, but yeah it stops when any of the sublists is exhausted, ie: `assert [[1,2,3,4],['a','b'],['i','ii','iii']].transpose() == [[1, 'a', 'i'], [2, 'b', 'ii']]`